# Txt file adding line breaks in html file

Tags: jquery, html

I have a txt file with fixtures of upcoming football games in the format

```
Northampton vs Bury <br>
Rochdale vs Southend <br>
Peterborough vs Oxford  <br
```

I'm then inserting it into my html file with the following jQuery code

```
$('#GamesTable').load("Fixtures/League1.txt");
```

however when I open the page the games appear to be 2 line breaks down as though the file has started with

```
<br> <br>
```

which it hasn't. 
Some of my other txt files with other fixtures however appear to only add 1 line break and some don't add any. Any ideas why this would be?

Comment: Perhaps it is something to do with \r\n, when you hit enter in, let's say Notepad, a \n character is saved (or somethings \r\n depending on OS). Maybe the `.load()` reads these as `<br>` and appends it - perhaps inconsistent OSes will make some files save with \r\n and some with \n only?

Comment: loads fine for me. in which browser are you testing?

Comment: Using Safari @KiranShakya.

Comment: That would make sense but I immediately have text and then no line break till after the first fixture @BrandonNguyen

Comment: which jQuery version and Safari version you are testing in? It is stated that if you are using Safari 5.1 or older you should use jQuery v1.12 or older. https://jquery.com/browser-support/.    And one more thing you should check your developer tool console to see if any errors occur during the .load() call.

Comment: Using Safari version 10.0 so that should all be fine, interestingly have just tried the site on Chrome and have the same problem.  http://tinypic.com/r/53aj29/9 shows my problem. Developer console is throwing up no issues either @KiranShakya

Comment: Your txt file part has worked properly in my test and according to the image you uploaded, it worked properly. Problem is, you have not provided the previous lines of txt file which seem to have problem.

Comment: I have solved the problem now thanks @KiranShakya. It was my own fault, due to there not been enough lines of fixtures the browser wasp using the text file down to the bottom of the div giving the appearance of adding line breaks.